# Деепричастные обороты разного вида

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот

Однородные деепричастные обороты, зависящие от одного глагола, иногда бывают разного вида. Может кто-нибудь привести справочник, где об этом будет сказано? Или может кто-нибудь привести такие примеры? Мне не удалось ничего найти.

Comment: Интересный вопрос, Серж, но у меня нет пока ни однозначного мнения, ни его доказательства. В то же время я предлагаю вспомнить тему однородных и неоднородных определений. Там формальная грамматика одинаковая, а семантика разная.  Также можно использовать проверку однородности для примеров с помощью союз И

Comment: @Sharon, рад, что вы ответили. Да, мне тоже не удалось найти источники, где-бы об этом говорилось. Но зато удалось найти источник, где говорится о правомерности однородных сказуемых разного вида. https://scicenter.online/yazyik-russkiy-scicenter/trudnyie-voprosyi-grammatiki-pravopisaniya.html

Comment: Да, Серж, КЛАССНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ. Получается, что  сказуемые разного вида однородны, если их можно привести к одному моменту времени, и этот момент задан семантикой . Для деепричастных оборотов момент задан глаголом-сказуемым и временными наречиями. Также для проверки можно использовать ОБОБЩАЮЩЕЕ слово, например: Расправив крылья, лишь изредка трогая ими воздух, орлы начали стремительно выписывать огромные круги (как они это делали?).  Это, как я думаю, однородные деепричастия. А остальные примеры надо тоже проверять.

Comment: А вот на сайте Studfiles написано: Нельзя употреблять в одном предложении деепричастия разного вида, например: ***Слушая лекцию и законспектировав излагаемый преподавателем материал, я всегда готовлюсь к следующему занятию.***

Comment: @Sharon https://studfile.net/preview/7456882/page:5/

Comment: Некорректное даже на слух предложение, неудачный, и надуманный пример, Тут дело не только в разном виде деепричастий. Правильно сказать так: Слушая лекцию и конспектируя излагаемый преподавателем материал, я готовлюсь к следующему занятию.  Наречие "всегда" тут совершенно ни при чем, как говорится, "притянуто за уши".

Comment: Согласен с вами.

Comment: И здесь ещё: https://reallanguage.club/grammatika-russkogo-yazyka/grammaticheskie-oshibki/grammaticheskie-oshibki-v-deeprichastiyax/

Comment: @oleedd А это, из приведенной статьи,  правильно? "Читая статью и отмечая нужный материал, я всегда делаю выписки".  Где тут обозначено время действия, наречием "всегда"? Сначала он читает и отмечает, а потом делает выписки? Или все одновременно, читает, пишет?   Тогда уж так: Читая статью, я всегда отмечаю нужный материал и делаю выписки. Другими словами, не надо ВЫДУМЫВАТЬ сомнительные примеры, а надо брать их из реальной разговорной или художественной речи.

Comment: Да,  Sharon, примеры надуманы.

Comment: Мало того, если следовать их логике, нужно написать так: Прочитав материал и отметив нужный материал, я всегда делаю выписки. Даже исправленный вариант мне кажется неверным из-за наречия всегда.

Comment: @Sharon Там вообще получается образ действия: *Я всегда делаю выписки (как? каким образом?) читая статью и отмечая нужный материал.* При таком порядке "всегда" уместно. Но да, действия последовательные. Вроде бы обязательна одновременность (нет исключений). Может, под "делать" подразумевается весь процесс работы над выписками: *— Чем ты занимаешься? — Делаю выписки.* А допустимость "читая, отмечаю" и подобного (несколько раз попадалось) — сложный вопрос (действия же не одновременные).

Comment: Да, образ действия, а  одинаковое обстоятельственное значение - это необходимое условие для однородности. Но это еще не все, нужно обобщение действий, раскрывающее одну тему. при этом временные наречия должны этому соответствовать. И где все это?  Таким образом, стилистика сомнительная, а примеры надо не выдумывать, а приводить из литературы. Поэтому нет у меня доверия к этому материалу, ничему он меня не учит. Обороты разного вида чаще бывают неоднородными, но однородные тоже могут встретиться. Поэтому не надо обобщать или надо делать это убедительно, на литературе. Нужно там искать ошибки.

Comment: Литературу обычно берут как правильное для анализа. Авторы настолько неправильно не пишут, там такого не найти. Между реально однородными можно "и" вставить, такое вряд ли найдётся. Есть два варианта прочтения первого примера про орлов (перечислительная интонация и с отнесением первого деепричастия к деепричастию с глаголом, как в остальных примерах), интересно, как правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне думается, что если однородные сказуемые могут быть выражены глаголами разных видов, то почему же деепричастным оборотам, от них образованным, — нельзя?

Можно. Вот предложения одного автора, которые часто используются в проверочных заданиях, связанных с пунктуацией (видоизмененные, правда):

***Расправив** бурые, со светлыми пёстринами, ловкие и чуткие крылья, лишь изредка **трогая** ими воздух, орлы начали стремительно выписывать в раздольном поднебесье огромные круги.*

*Едва **коснувшись** земли, орел сделал несколько сильных, порывистых прыжков, **расплескивая** помятый ковыль, затем вдруг замер на месте и предостерегающе щелкнул стальным клювом.*

*Иногда, **заспорив** о чем-то, они бросались друг на друга, гулко **хлопая** тугими крыльями, а спустя время, успокоясь, видели, что все собранное для гнезда было раскидано вокруг или висело на ветках таволожки.*

[М. С. Бубеннов. Орлиная степь](https://librebook.me/orlinaia_step/vol2/1)

Comment: Спасибо, Римма. На одном из форумов, был задан вопрос об однородных деепричастных оборотах разного вида. Я не смог ответить из-за того, что не было ссылок не на примеры, ни на правила.

Comment: Когда они по обе стороны, они не сильно однородные. Структура: *деепричастие {сказуемое с деепричастием}*. А в первом примере смягчение за счёт "лишь изредка". Союз "и" между ними не вставишь (а это основной критерий). То есть используются приёмы, чтобы сроднить неоднородные вещи.